# How to display textbox input value to another view in ASP.net core MVC (without ORM)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm currently working on a Travel agency website and I need to get the input of a textbox to another view. I want to use cookies or something like that to make this happen. How can I implement this?

Comment: You can use the Session or TempData

Comment: @ADyson Do you know a tutorial or something like that, that shows me how to implement this with Session or Tempdata?

Comment: @adyson yes I did. I've tried multiple implementations, didnt work and they weren't that clear to me.

Comment: Well at least show what you tried please. Probably easier to try and correct that than to guess what tutorial might suit you